# What is the actual number for the Winsocks definition of FIONBIO?

Tags: c, sockets, winsock

I'm working in an interpreted scripting language that does not support system include files.

I need numbers for many of the Winsock #defines.
For most I can just search the files and get an answer like:

```
#define AF_INET6  23
```

But for FIONBIO I see

```
#define FIONBIO   _IOW('f', 126, u_long)
```

looking up _IOW shows

```
#define _IOW(x,y,t)      (IOC_IN|(((long)sizeof(t)&IOCPARM_MASK)<<16)|((x)<<8)|(y))
```

I find some pieces for that:

```
#define IOCPARM_MASK      0x7f
#define IOC_IN    0x80000000
```

But I get lost somewhere in the turns when I try to figure out what that actually turns out to be.

Can anyone tell me what number FIONBIO is supposed to be?
I did find a post somewhere that casually mentioned that in some UNIX build there was:

```
#define FIONBIO         := 0x5421
```

I cannot seem to make the windows Winsock definition turn into that number, and I am uncertain as to whether it should be the same in any case.

Can someone tell me the answer?  Or do I have to download some windows development environment and write a C program to print out the value? :)

Comment: Thank you.  Funny thing is that is the answer I got when trying to decode the syntax manually, but I did not believe it could be correct.  Live and learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <winsock.h>

int main()
{
    printf("FIONBIO is size %u with value %u (0x%x)\n", 
        sizeof(FIONBIO), FIONBIO, FIONBIO);
}
```

gives the output;

```
FIONBIO is size 4 with value 2147772030 (0x8004667e)
```

Comment: `ioctlsocket`'s cmd parameter is a long, so the actual value of FIONBIO should be printed with `%ld` and is -2147195266

Comment: Be careful with the implicit data type convertion as @tmm1 says